# ClassCastException with JDBM2

Tags: java, persistence

I have a large Map that I want to persist using JDBM2 (first time user of JDBM2).

I've made a few simple edits to a JDBM2 demo program.  However, when I extract a stored value I get a ClassCast Exceptions.

Here is the code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Also, is it possible to use JDBM2 in this way.  The examples don't build,close,reopen,use.  They build,use,close]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    /** open db */
    RecordManager recman = RecordManagerFactory.createRecordManager("hugedata");
    PrimaryTreeMap<String, double[][]> db = recman.treeMap("hugemap");

    /** insert some records */
    int aBigNumber = 1000;
    int aSmallerNumber = 100;
    for (long i = 0; i < aBigNumber; i++) {

        db.put(Long.toString(i), new double[9][9]);

        if (i % aSmallerNumber == 0) {
            /** Commit periodically, otherwise program would run out of memory */
            recman.commit();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    recman.commit();
    recman.close();

    //now that the database is built we need to load it from file...otherwise we are cheating

    //open the database to use it...
    recman = RecordManagerFactory.createRecordManager("hugedata");
    PrimaryTreeMap<String, double[][]> revivedDB = recman.treeMap("hugemap");

    //ClassCastException thrown here
    double[][] aStoredValue = revivedDB.get(Long.toString(10));

    recman.close();

    System.out.println("DONE");

}
```